# how can check if server and port is available in nodejs ?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have project with is written with Nodejs. I need to know how to check if an IP with Port is working to connect to.

EX: 
Check example1.com 443 =>true ;
Check example1.com 8080 =>false

Thanks

Comment: Try connecting to it and then have a failure callback?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The only way to know if a server/port is available is to try to actually connect to it.  If you knew that the server responded to ping, you could run a ping off the server, but that just tells you if the host is running and responding to ping, it doesn't directly tell you if the server process you want to connect to is running and accepting connections.

The only way to actually know that it is running and accepting connections is to actually connect to it and report back whether it was successful or not (note this is an asynchronous operation):

```
var net = require('net');
var Promise = require('bluebird');

function checkConnection(host, port, timeout) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        timeout = timeout || 10000;     // default of 10 seconds
        let socket, timer;
        timer = setTimeout(function() {
            reject(new Error(`timeout trying to connect to host ${host}, port ${port}`));
            socket.end();
        }, timeout);
        socket = net.createConnection(port, host, function() {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            resolve();
            socket.end();
        });
        socket.on('error', function(err) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            reject(err);
        });
    });
}

checkConnection("example1.com", 8080).then(function() {
    // successful
}, function(err) {
    // error
})
```

Comment: Thanks u. I have tried but Result is fasle for every case :(

Comment: @rubiken - I'm not sure what you mean by the "result is false".  This function does not return `true` or `false` - it calls one of two asynchronous callbacks.  I tested the code myself and (after fixing a typo) it works for me.

Comment: @jfriend00 - I'm using this answer with `webtorrent` and `torrent-discovery` to test discovered peers and ignore unresponsive ones. Do you believe this code presents any kind of security issues in that kind of a use case?

Comment: @Dshiz - I don't really understand your use case and that type of security threats is not really my specialty.  If you're connecting to unknown/untrusted endpoints, then you need to protect against any malicious behavior they might throw at you via the connected socket.  This code closes the socket as soon as its connected so I'm not sure what else that would be.

Comment: @jfriend00 - thanks for the feedback. I don't know a lot about security/cryptography, so I'm not sure what malicious behavior I would need to protect against. I'm just going to put my library out there and hopefully someone who knows better than I will chime in with suggestions. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

One small correction after trying this code. Using `socket.end()` will always cause a connection reset error, thereby calling both resolve and reject. If you use this code in classic callback, use `socket.destroy()` instead

Comment: i don't think it's possible to call resolve and reject both on same promise... it will either be resolve or reject.