# Check several different TCP/IP services for availability?

Tags: node.js

Let's say I have a list of hostnames and ports, not all of which are HTTP related.

```
var config = {
  "checks": [
    {
      "name": "NPM",
      "hostname": "npmjs.com",
      "port": 80
    },
    {
      "name": "AWS",
      "hostname": "aws.amazon.com",
      "port": 443
    },
    {
      "name": "RabbitMQ",
      "hostname": "merry-butterfly.rmq.cloudamqp.com",
      "port": 5671
    }
  ]
}
```

What is an effective way to test that each of these services can be reached? My first thoughts were to use a typical telnet-like approach, I did this:

```
var telnet = require('telnet-client')

config.checks.forEach(function(check) {
  var connection = new telnet()

  var params = {
    host: check.hostname,
    port: check.port,
    negotiationMandatory: false
  }

  connection.on('connect', function() {
    connection.send('GET /', {
      ors: '\r\n', 
      waitfor: '\n'
    }, function(err, data) {
      console.log(err, data);
      connection.end()
    })
  })

  connection.connect(params)
  results.push(result);
});
```

The above seems to work, but I'm actually not sure what data to send to each individual services to get back a response that suggests the service is "reachable", I don't need to auth or do any operations with the service, just check that it *can* be reached. Additionally it raises an exception if the DNS is unreachable:

```
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND merry-butterfly.rmq.cloudamqp.com/api merry-butterfly.rmq.cloudamqp.com/api:443
```

What would be the appropriate way to handle the errors, and async test each of the entries in the list of "checks"?

Comment: If you're just looking to see if you can get a connection, then you can use this type of code: [how can check if server and port is available in nodejs ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29069111/how-can-check-if-server-and-port-is-available-in-nodejs/29069322#29069322).

Comment: Also, somewhat related: [Portscan in Node doesn't work if port range is too wide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36814081/portscan-in-node-doesnt-work-if-port-range-is-too-wide/36814411#36814411) as this tests a lot of different ports for availability and could be adapted to use different hosts on the same port.

Comment: You can't send any data to the serve you connect to unless you code for the exact type of data each service is expecting.  For example, if it's an http service, then you need to format an appropriate http request as the data to send.  If it's some other protocol, then you have to send data appropriate to that protocol.  Though, you don't need to send any data to it to see that it is at least responding to incoming connections.  That only takes making a TCP connection to it and seeing that the connection succeeded and that it's ready to send data to.

Comment: Great feedback @jfriend00, thank you, I'll try the solution you linked to.

Comment: Don't use a telnet client, just use a TCP socket. See https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_net_createconnection_port_host_connectlistener for details. Listen for connect and error events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ping the host.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ping

For example:

```
var ping = require('ping');

var hosts = ['192.168.1.1', 'google.com', 'yahoo.com'];
hosts.forEach(function(host){
    ping.sys.probe(host, function(isAlive){
        var msg = isAlive ? 'host ' + host + ' is alive' : 'host ' + host + ' is dead';
        console.log(msg);
    });
});
```

Comment: @JPSilvashy It will work for any protocol, as long as the remote server answers pings. If it doesn't answer pings, it will require a custom made solution (if it kindly answers to something) or it won't be possible at all if the remote server uses some kind of encryption and only reacts to some key you don't have.

Comment: This tells you only if a host is answering pings (which is its own server process).  It does not tell you if the host is answering on the specific port you're looking for a specific service on.  There are some services that specifically do not enable ping responses on their hosts and there can certainly be hosts that do support ping responses, but for which the actual server process you're looking for is down and not responding or not even there.  So, if this answers yes, then you know only that host is online.  If it doesn't answer, you don't really know what that means.

Comment: @jfriend00 According to your logic, a host answering on the specific port you're looking for a specific service on is not a guarantee that the service is available either. It could be partially unavailable. If you don't understand availability as reachability, you have to create a replica of the client and check that every possible call to the server answers as it should, then you can say it's available.

Comment: Yeah, but it tells you more than a ping does.  You can't really make a positive decision either way with a ping.  If it doesn't respond, that doesn't mean the actual service you want isn't there and if it does respond, that doesn't mean the service is there.  So, you can't draw any conclusion.  At least with my suggestions, if nothing responds, then you definitively know the service is not responding.  If it is connecting, you know that the host is there and if you want more than that, then you have to send a well-formed client request for that protocol.  That's all there is to it.

Comment: The only way to tell if any given remote service is alive and fully operational is to ask it to service every request in the way it's meant to - in fact it's the only way to truly know something is working correctly. 
Ping allows to check whether or not the server is reachable, as long as it answers pings.
Your suggested links don't really allow anything. Majority of services won't answer a request unless it is specifically crafted for that service. So if nothing responds, you can't know for sure the service is not responding. If it responds, you can't know if the service is fully available.